# macos - < and ' keys swapped

Tags: macos, keyboard, text-input

I'm using a Varmilo VA88m Nordic layout external keyboard for my macbook, I've been using it with relatively little problems until now when the < - key, and the ' - key have been swapped. I have not found any solution to this that works.

I tried the tip in the photo below, but this didn't cahnge anything, but now whenever i pres the "Change keyboard type" key in keyboard settings, it registers my external keyboard as my built in one.

[image]

Any ideas? Stuck for ages trying to figure it out, happened so suddenly and I am completely out of clues. Preferable any fixes that don't include Karabiner-Elements, tried it before and it only gave me more problems...

EDIT: This is the message i get when i try to use the "Change keyboard type" in settings :[image]

Comment: Did you get a resolution on this? Because I have the same problem. The <-key is now the §-key. When I look at System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources, the keyboard at first look like the ISO keyboard it's supposed to be but when I press the '§' key, the layout changes to a ANSI layout.

Comment: Honestly not really, I currently don’t have the issue but it reappers at random times. Think the way i fixed it before was by re installing karabiner elements, but still the issue does come back. Still no luck woth a permanent fix.

Comment: I've been in contact with Varmilo and they've sent me a patch file. Haven't been able to apply it yet.

Comment: And now I have and it worked. While I can share it with you, I'm not really certain that it will really work.

Comment: Ah, my fix still works for now so I'm good. Good that it worked for you.