# Problems with Varmilo VA88M keyboard, seems to switch to ANSI layout

Tags: macos, keyboard, text-input

I have, since some 2 months, a VA88M Varmilo keyboard (and am very happy with it), a ISO Nordic keyboard layout. 
Suddenly it switched some keys around so that the >-key suddenly generated °-char and the < key generated §. 
I removed the `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` and KeyboardSetupAssistent appeared and I could fix it. (as suggested [here][1]) but it only worked for a while. Now the file doesn't exist anymore and when I try to run KeyBoardSetupAssistent manually it just says that there is no unknown keyboard.

Help me out here, please!
I've also mailed Varmilo but they had no good ideas.

UPDATE
So I got a patch file from Varmilo. It worked for a while but then turned on the backlighting permanently which was very aggravating. I mailed them again and got another patch file and that one turned it back to the original problem. By then I started thinking that it might be a hw problem so I returned the keyboard and got another one. After a while that one also went ANSI. So I've moved to using karabiner and keeping the kbd in windows mode. Very disappointing though the keyboard is very sweet mechanically.
[1]: [macos - < and ' keys swapped](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401236/macos-and-keys-swapped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed with Varmilo and they sent me a patch file. Once I successfully applied the patch, the keyboard (at least so far) works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem using the program [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/). I selected:

- `Simple Modifications` tab
- `Varmilo Keyboard (AONE)` target device
- Created a new mapping from `` grave_accent_and_tilde (`) `` to `non_us_backslash`
- Created another mapping from `non_us_backslash` to `` grave_accent_and_tilde (`) ``.

This fixed the keyboard mapping issue both on the MacBook internal and external keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

One possible fix is to create a custom layout with

https://software.sil.org/ukelele/

Which puts <> where you want it.

Comment: I've looked into ukelele but would prefer to avoid if possible since, in my mind, something's actually wrong with the keyboard. I've once again been in contact with Varmilo and this time they've sent me a firmware patch (to the kbd) that I have yet to apply.

Comment: Let us know if the patch works.  A custom layout is a last resort when nothing else seems to work to fix intermittent keyboard type glitches.

Comment: And it worked !